# Using YUI 3 to trace jQuery.extend

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, yui

I'm trying to use YUI 3 to track the performance of jQuery in our application.  IE8 is complaining of a slow running script, which on debugging appears to be internal to jQuery (the extend function).

I've managed to get YUI to trace the calls of jQuery, but not the extend function itself using the following code:

```
//create new instance and load profiler
YUI().use("profiler", function(Y){

  Y.Profiler.registerConstructor("jQuery", window);

  window.YProfiler = Y.Profiler;
});
```

This tracks specific calls to jQuery but not jQuery.extend - which according to IE is causing the problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `registerFunction` after `registerConstructor`:

```
Y.Profiler.registerConstructor("jQuery", window);
Y.Profiler.registerFunction("jQuery.extend");
```

**References**

- [YUI Profiler: registerFunction](https://yui.github.io/yui2/docs/yui_2.9.0_full/profiler/)